# Communicate with custom receiver app from chrome on iOS

Tags: ios, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast, mobile-chrome

I have a custom sender and receiver app that both work as expected on desktop. However if I try to run my app from chrome on iOS I run into issues.

Based on the info Im gathering from debugging the receiver app, it is getting into my castReceiverManager.onSenderConnected function and I can log out the event.data and useragent (iOS CastSDK,,iPhone,iPhone OS,8.1.2). It never gets into where I listen for onMessage though.

```
window.messageBus = window.castReceiverManager.getCastMessageBus('urn:x-cast:com.whatever');

window.messageBus.onMessage = function(event) {
    console.log('Message [' + event.senderId + ']: ' + event.data);
}
```

UPDATE:  A year later and I still haven't figured this out.

Comment: Did you happen to find an answer to this?

Comment: Not really.  According to someone on google+ only native apps are supported but they gave no explanation.  https://plus.google.com/117159689137765565047/posts/ZMg7H7csui3

Comment: I'll ask around and will get back to you

Comment: @f.lorenzo did you figure anything out?

Comment: no sorry, i'm 100% sure that it did work once. But maybe they disabled it now? I'm now moving over to do Cordova instead to support it.. Oh wel..