# Can I start a Google Cast session from Chrome on iOS or Android?

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

About 5-6 years ago, I asked this same question and I'm trying to figure out if anything has changed since that time.  I have a Google Cast Custom Receiver that I need to start up via a website.  I don't need to send any information/messages to the receiver, it just needs to start up.

Obviously, I know I can do this from a native app on either iOS and Android, but my users will not install an app just to start a cast session -- I need to be able to do it from a browser.

Does the Google Cast API support this yet?  If so, how do I do it?

Here are related questions with really dated answers:

[Communicate with custom receiver app from chrome on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27762558/communicate-with-custom-receiver-app-from-chrome-on-ios)

[How can I cast an HTML page with the Google Cast Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27049265/how-can-i-cast-an-html-page-with-the-google-cast-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this, so I cannot give you a definitive answer. However, the most recent Chrome Cast [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/chrome_sender#requirements) specifies this:

> The Chrome Sender SDK supports the Chrome browser on a Mac, Windows, Linux, ChromeOS, and Android devices. (For native mobile Cast applications see Android Apps and iOS Apps instead.)
>
> > Note: Casting is not supported on the iOS Chrome browser.

Without being able to confirm this, you will likely be able to access the cast sender functionality from a Chrome browser on **Android**, but definitely not on iOS.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I found, too, although I haven't been able to get it to work on Chrome for Android yet.  Chrome on my Mac works fine, but neither mobile platform seems to work.